# gmate error - no module named gconf when trying to open gmate

Tags: python, ruby, linux, ubuntu

When trying to open gmate editor (installed it for ruby), i get this error:
"ImportError: no module named gconf"

my python version is 2.7.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you do not have the python bindings for gconf installed.

On Ubuntu, you would need to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gconf
```

... or the equivalent command for CentOS:

```
sudo yum install gnome-python2-gconf
```